# error 1258 when restoring from Actifio

Tags: backup, google-cloud-platform, google, restore

I am using ActifioGo on Google Cloud and took a snapshot. When I try to restore it, I get an error message like:

```
1258: Cloud VM creation failed. 155: VM task failed. Error: Cloud task failed 
gcp:createvmfromimage:us-central1-a:123456....789:projectname:
act-image-snap-bastion-123-456.
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

The service account used by Actifio must have the privileges to perform the restore operation. To make sure this is the case, go to Actifio Go Manager - manage - credentials. Note the service account name, it will be similar to 123465789-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com

Go to Google Cloud Console, change to the correct project (the error message contains the project name). Select IAM & Admin -> IAM. Select the service account (in this example 123456789-compute...) and assign the role Custom -> ActifioGo which has been installed by Actifio.